# R Shiny app keeps returning the error “no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class ”NULL“” for ggplot

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

Apologies in advance for the long block of code, but this is for a Shiny app I'm building in R. I've narrowed the issue down to the ggplot() set of code within the server section by using the browser() function. Everything works up until there, but then I get the error "no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "NULL"".

This morning I added the reactive section following "new_projections <-" and it was working just fine before that, but now I keep getting that error. Any suggestions?

```
    if(interactive()){

## load required packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(agridat)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

## load latest projections from fantasypros
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samhoppen/2020_FF_Analysis/master/Functions/fpros_scrape_projections.R")
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samhoppen/2020_FF_Analysis/master/Functions/set_vor.R")
# define inputs
position <- c("qb", "rb", "wr", "te")
week <- "draft"

# crossing for all combos of inputs
crossing(position, week)

# scrape the data
projections <- crossing(position = position, week = week) %>% 
    pmap_dfr(scrape_projections) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(pass_yds, rush_yds, rec_yds), str_remove, ",") %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(pass_att:rec_tds), as.numeric) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(team:position), as.factor) %>% 
    select(-c("week")) %>% 
    as_tibble()

## set all NA values to 0
projections[is.na(projections)] = 0

## set_vor function


ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            p("Select draft settings"),
            selectInput(inputId = "league_size",
                        label = "1. Select league size",
                        choices = c("8", "10", "12", "14", "16"), selected = "12"),
            radioButtons(inputId = "scoring",
                         label = "3. Select scoring type",
                         choices = c("Non PPR", "Half PPR", "Full PPR"), selected = "Half PPR"),
            tags$p("Select starting lineup"),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                         label = "Number of starting QBs",
                         value = 1,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                         label = "Number of starting RBs",
                         value = 2,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                         label = "Number of starting WRs",
                         value = 3,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_tes",
                         label = "Number of starting TEs",
                         value = 1,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_flex",
                         label = "Number of starting flex spots",
                         value = 1,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6),
            numericInput(inputId = "starting_superflex",
                         label = "Number of starting superflex spots",
                         value = 0,
                         min = 0,
                         max = 6)),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("draftPlot")
            )
        )
    )


    server <- function(input, output) {
        new_projections <- reactive({
            lg_type <- input$scoring
            req(projections)

            if(lg_type == "Non PPR"){
                projections %>% 
                    mutate(fpts = (pass_yds * 0.04) +
                               (pass_tds * 4) +
                               (pass_ints * -2) +
                               (rush_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rush_tds * 6) + 
                               (fl * -2) +
                               (rec_rec * 0) +
                               (rec_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rec_tds * 6))
            }

            if(lg_type == "Half PPR"){
                projections %>% 
                    mutate(fpts = (pass_yds * 0.04) +
                               (pass_tds * 4) +
                               (pass_ints * -2) +
                               (rush_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rush_tds * 6) + 
                               (fl * -2) +
                               (rec_rec * 0.5) +
                               (rec_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rec_tds * 6))
            }

            if(lg_type == "Full PPR"){
                projections %>% 
                    mutate(fpts = (pass_yds * 0.04) +
                               (pass_tds * 4) +
                               (pass_ints * -2) +
                               (rush_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rush_tds * 6) + 
                               (fl * -2) +
                               (rec_rec * 1) +
                               (rec_yds * 0.1) +
                               (rec_tds * 6))
            }
        })

        default_baseline <- reactive({
            req(input$starting_qbs, input$starting_superflex,
                input$starting_rbs, input$starting_flex, input$league_size,
                input$starting_wrs, input$starting_tes)
            lg_sz <- as.numeric(input$league_size)
            st_flx <- as.numeric(input$starting_flex)
            st_sflx <- as.numeric(input$starting_superflex)
            st_qbs <- as.numeric(input$starting_qbs)
            st_rbs <- as.numeric(input$starting_rbs)
            st_wrs <- as.numeric(input$starting_wrs)
            st_tes <- as.numeric(input$starting_tes)
            c(QB = (lg_sz * (st_qbs + st_sflx) * 1.25),
              RB = ((lg_sz * (st_rbs + st_flx) * 1.5) + (st_sflx * lg_sz * 0.5)),
              WR = ((lg_sz * (st_wrs + st_flx) * 1.5) + (st_sflx * lg_sz * 0.5)),
              TE = ((lg_sz * (st_tes +(st_flx * 0.5))) + (st_sflx * lg_sz * 0.25)))
        })

        vor_table <- reactive(
            set_vor(new_projections(),
                    vor_baseline = default_baseline(),
                    vor_var = "fpts"))

        output$draftPlot <- renderPlot({
            ggplot() +
                geom_smooth(data = vor_table(),
                            aes(x = vor_table()$fpts_rank, y = vor_table()$fpts_vor),
                            color = "firebrick",
                            linetype = "dashed",
                            size = 1,
                            method = "loess",
                            formula = y ~ x,
                            se = FALSE)
        })
    }
```

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: When asking for help please make sure to provide just a **minimal** example. Take out any code that's not directly related to the problem but still can be run. Include only packages that are absolutely necessary. Often you'll find the problem yourself when making the example minimal.

Comment: Sometimes this is because the plot attempts to happen before data is available. Consider looking at `req` in your reactive/observe blocks, as they keep the reactive block from running if the data is absent or empty. (As MrFlick just said ... I'm not going to look through this whole code to find if/where this might be happening. Please reduce the problem to the minimum required to reproduce your problem.)

Comment: The problem is likely your `new_projections` element is return NULL. You'll probably want to turn those subsequent `if` statements into an `if/else` chain otherwise you won't get the return value you want. Only the last expression returns anything in block and an `if` statement return NULL if the condition is false. The block doesn't "remember" the last true value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone and I appreciate your feedback. Still trying to get better at producing a minimal reprex. I've narrowed it down as much as I could. Like I mentioned in the original post, it's occurring in the ggplot section when trying to load that. Thanks for your help!!